# The fastest way to find correspondence in two lists Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list `lst1` of objects that have attribute `from_id`. Also, I have another list `lst2` of objects that have attribute `to_id`.

I need to find for each object in `lst1` its "pair" in `lst2` (`from_id` should equal `to_id`).

There can be at most one object (zero or one) from `lst2` that corresponds to the given object from `lst1`.

What is the fastest way to achieve it in python?

Comment: Inner looping, but it gives O(n^2) and very slow when lists have more than 100 items.

Comment: It depends on your objects. But, most probably NumPy would help. For example, here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534500/whats-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-large-lists-of-1s-0s-and-return-the-di)

Answer (score 0):

Use **sets**; as it works like a dict without keys (just values). Convert your lists into sets first.

```
lst1 = set(lst1)
lst2 = set(lst2)

res = [(obj, to_obj) for obj in lst1 for to_obj in lst2 if obj.from_id == to_obj.to_id]
```

This can be broken to

```
result = []
for obj in lst1:
    for to_obj in lst2:
        if obj.from_id == to_obj.to_id:
            result.append((obj, to_obj))
            break
```

This will end with a list of tuples.
The longer version breaks what the object is found, the comprehension code doesn't.